# Azure Active Directory (B2E) vs Azure Active Directory B2C - the information out there is ambiguous and difficult to follow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Dear Microsoft Azure AD personnel, (and anyone else who has been down this road)

We are building a User Interface as a front-end to our back-end architecture in Azure, mainly comprised of Azure SQL databases, VM clusters, Azure Search indexes, and SFC's.

Users who will login to this UI will be both internal (company employees) and external (our clients).  The internal users will log in to perform various functions for services we provide our clients.  Our clients will log in to perform search queries on certain tables of our databases.

Where we are lost is in the area of trying to plan and execute our identity management architecture along the lines of permissions and policies.

For our **internal users**, we will have several different permissions profiles that need to be defined - for example, User 1 should be able to access and write information about client 1, but not client 2.  User 2 should be able to access and write information about client 2 and client 3, but not client 1.  That is just a simple example.

For our **clients**, thus far, we have set a up a B2C tenant to allow them to sign-up for access with their email address.  While this part is simple and straight-forward, it seems the B2C functionality is rather limited in that there are only policies for signup/sign-in, password reset, and profile editing.  We will eventually need to offer different levels of access permissions to our clients as well.

Here are my questions:

1. For our internal users, should we be using our domain Azure AD (B2E), or should we also use B2C for them so **all** users are under the B2C architecture?
2. Are these different kinds of permissions I've mentioned defined and set inside Active Directory settings, or coded into the Application?
3. Should we use B2C at all, given that we will need to give different permissions structures to different users within our clients?  Should we be using B2E for our clients as well, even though they are customers and not internal users on our domain?

I've been reading Azure documentation and watching videos since end of last week and I'm still having trouble determining what's right for us for what we're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What are SFC's?  And what is B2E?  Do you mean Azure AD B2B?

Comment: Service Fabric Cluster.  Not entirely relevant to AD specifically but wanted to give a full picture of our back-end.  B2E is Business 2 Enterprise and is how all the MS folks I've talked to refer to Azure Active Directory for your company's internal domain that controls enterprise applications, such as Office 365.  My understanding of B2B is that it's specific to collaboration with outside organizations.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for clarifying.  I've never heard B2E, maybe an internal jargon thing.

Comment: Yeah quite possibly.

Comment: @Stpete111 that is also the context I've heard B2E used for, although referring to business-to-employee.

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means an expert in Azure AD (either the most generic enterprise/domain, B2C, or B2B), but based on my reading and experiments:

1) You can funnel all users through AAD B2C, using AAD B2C custom policies to allow enterprise/domain AAD users to be connected to your AAD B2C directory; this means your application(s) only have to integrate with a single directory (AAD B2C);

2) None of the AAD flavors is really designed to do fine-grained permissions/authorization; you will probably need to handle this in your own code, or using some other feature/service.

Martin

Comment: Thanks Martin.  What you mention in #1 makes the most sense to me.  Regarding #2, I was afraid of this.  If you know of any Azure services, or other 3rd party tools that would assist us with this, please do let me know.  We've lost our main developer and we're looking for something that can be managed outside the code as much as possible, for now anyway.

Comment: @Stpete111: I am currently working through similar design/issues, rewriting a client's ASP.Net webfom app to MVC running in Azure.  I will be using M-Herbener's #1 for authentication.  For role authorization, I am considering adding custom properties to B2C user profiles, and add those to the claims in a custom IPrincipal and custom AuthorizeAttribute extensions.  I may just handle the roles in database table, though, looks easier to maintain. But either way, will still have custom IPrincipal/AuthorizeAttribute to enforce role authorization.